# Chrome Extension Pull JQuery from page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, kendo-ui

I'm working on an extension that is designed to extend functionality of exactly one page on our work intranet, one which uses the Kendo UI JQuery plugin, which I don't have access to. Because of that, including jQuery in my manifest won't solve my problem.

My extension doesn't seem to see the jQuery+plugin import that's loaded on the page. Is there something I can do to get around that? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at content script limitations in the first section here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: Not much clear about your question... Could you please provide more details? Like what actually you want, what you did and what's the error?